# PAM filtering via IP for SSH

Tags: ssh, password, pam

I know this is probably a bit of a nube question, but I need some input.
So if I use `last` I can see my IP, and it's also in my auth log whether failed or accepted, eg.

> Dec  9 19:30:16 wilhelm sshd[14211]: Failed password for root from 59.63.188.44 port 16257 ssh2

I want to know whether it is possible to only allow connections from IP's from a certain ISP.
e.g. if I do whois X.X.X.X on my IP and grep for ISP:

```
root@wilhelm:~# whois X.X.X.X|grep <ISPNAME>
netname:        <ISPNAME>
```

So is it possible to add this to pam for SSH connections?
Are there any disadvantages to this approach(except being locked out when in another location(portknocking maybe))?
It's on a VPS so I'm not worried about internet dropping out. I can just use VNC if I absolutely have to.
I have done a few quick searches on this and I'll continue to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly by PAM, but yes, it is possible to do. You can set this up using `tcp_wrappers` by modifying your `/etc/hosts.allow`, if your distro provides you the `aclexec` extension:

```
sshd: aclexec whois %a | grep <ISPNAME>
```

Or you can wrap the command into script that you can easily call.

More info can be found in manual page for [`hosts_options(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/hosts_options.5.html).

Comment: On the exit code of `grep`, which is 0 for the matched output and 1 for not-matched output.

Comment: Ah okay cool :)